# How to Notify main thread that all Tasks inside async method are finished

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, c#-4.0, asynchronous

I am unit testing async Method which further call two methods but inside my test cases I want to wait for all the tasks to be completed by this method ( there may be background tasks too) so how should i notify my main thread ( the one method which i called) that all other background tasks (async) tasks are finished to proceed to next statement.